# Haskell: How do I append to a list of list of tuples?

Tags: list, haskell, append, tuples

Sorry, I just started learning Haskell. I don't understand how to append a tuple to each sublist.

My current list is:

```
[[("String", "String", 2.0)],[("String", "String", 2.0),("String", "String", 2.0)]]
```

I want to add a tuple in each sublist so my new list is:

```
[[("String", "String", 2.0),("String","String",0.0)],[("String", "String", 2.0),("String", "String", 2.0),("String","String",0.0)]]
```

I am trying to write a function but it keeps on giving me an error

```
append :: a -> [a] -> [a]
append i (x:xs) = x : append i xs
append i [] = i : []
```

Then I do:

```
map append ("String","String",0.0)
```

This gives me a lot of errors like incorrect "type-matching". I am not sure how to append in Haskell.

Comment: I am on the phone so can't give a proper answer, but what you want is `map (append ("String", "String", 0.0))`

Answer (score 2):

Type of `[[("String", "String", 2.0)],[("String", "String", 2.0),("String", "String", 2.0)]]` is `Fractional t => [[(String, String, t)]]`, or to simplify `[[(String, String, Double)]]`.

So, it order to append the element to every nested list, we need to have a function `(String, String, Double) -> [[(String, String, Double)]] -> [[(String, String, Double)]]`. In other words, `a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]`:

```
append :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
append x xs = map (\xss -> xss ++ [x]) xs
```

And finally

```
> append ("String","String",0.0) [[("String", "String", 2.0)],[("String", "String", 2.0),("String", "String", 2.0)]]
[[("String","String",2.0),("String","String",0.0)],[("String","String",2.0),("String","String",2.0),("String","String",0.0)]]
```

By the way, note that adding elements to the end of the list is O(n), thus  you might consider to add it to the beginning:

```
append' :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
append' x = map ((:) x)
```

Comment: `(x :)` is simpler